# Does there exists a maximal divergent subsequence for every unbounded positive sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $ \{ a_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset [0, + \infty) $ is an unbounded but not convergent to $+ \infty$ sequence.

Is it possibile to extract from it a "maximal divergent subsequence"? With this I mean if it is true that there exists a strictly increasing map $\phi: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ s.t. 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{k \to + \infty} a_{\phi(k)} &= + \infty \\
 \sup_{n \notin \phi(\mathbb{N})} a_n &< + \infty \\
\end{align*}

I think it could be possibile to use Zorn's lemma defining
$$ \mathcal{A} := \bigl \{ \phi : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \text{ strictly increasing} \mid \lim_{k \to + \infty} a_{\phi(k)} = + \infty \bigr \} $$
which is nonempty, with the order $\phi_1 \le \phi_2$ iff $\phi_1(\mathbb{N}) \subseteq \phi_2(\mathbb{N}) $. Then if $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathcal{A}$ is a chain I can take 
$$ B := \bigcup \bigl \{ \phi(\mathbb{N}) \mid \phi \in \mathcal{C} \bigr \} $$
and $\phi_0: \mathbb{N} \to B$ a surjective streactly increasing map. Then $\phi_0 \in \mathcal{A}$ and $\phi \le \phi_0$ for all $\phi \in \mathcal{C}$. Thus $\mathcal{A}$ has a maximal element $\bar{\phi}$ and I think it satisfies the two conditions I wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you take a union, you can lose the property of limit been infinity.

And it's impossible to find such subsequence in general. Take, for example, sequence $1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, \ldots, n, n - 1, \ldots, 2, 1, n + 1, n, \ldots$.

Let us take some subsequence. For $\sup$ of rest to be finite, we need to take all numbers larger than some $K$ in our subsequence. But for $\lim$ of our subsequence been infinite, we need to take at most finite number of elements equal to say $K + 1$ in our subsequence.

Thus subsequence has finite number of elements equal to $K + 1$, and rest of it has no such elements, but our original sequence had infinite number of such elements. Contradiction, thus subsequence we were looking for doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

For some sequences it isn't possible. Namely you could have a sequence $a_n$ such that for all $\alpha\in [0,\infty]$ there is some subsequence $a_{n_k}\to \alpha$. It is then clear that whatever subsequence $a_{n_k}\to \infty$ you select, if you parametrize the remaining indices in a single sequence $\{a_{m_k}\}$, then the set of limit points of $\{a_{m_k}\}_k$ will still have to contain $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Where can I find an example of such a sequence?

Comment: @Bremen000 by enumerating all positive rationals, for example.

Comment: @Bremen000 You can pick something like $$b_n=0,\frac12, 0,\frac13,\frac 23,\frac 34,\frac24,\frac 14,0,\frac15,\frac25,\frac 35,\frac 45,\frac 56,\frac46,\frac 36,\frac26,\frac16,0,\frac17,\frac27,\cdots$$ which has $[0,1]$ as set of cluster points by going back and forth, and then consider $a_n=\frac1{1-b_n}-1$

Comment: Provided the same idea works if the set of limit points is some unbounded set, like $\Bbb N$.